# Comma or period after the words: I remain at the end of a letter?

Tags: grammar

Do you ever place a period after remain?
For example:

With best wishes for a happy holiday, I remain.

Sincerely yours,

Comment: The period says nothing else follows, but your signature is supposedly following.  Therefore the comma.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "With best wishes for a happy holiday, I remain." you have two unrelated clauses, which is jarring to say the least. The only seeming ways to relate them is as an assertion that they are going on holiday and that you are making a point of noting that you are not.

The format:

"With best wishes for a happy holiday.

I remain sincerely yours,

Name"

This is still quite formal or "ceremonious" as this reference describes: [here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/yours-faithfully-or-yours-sincerely/), with the "I remain" further emphasising the formality.